# How to prove $n \geq \frac{(x_1+....+x_n)^2}{(x_1^2+.....+x_n^2)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Currently I try to solve an exercise in which I need to prove that the variance of estimator a is smaller or equal to the estimator. I simplified the equation to the point down below.

$ n \geq \frac{(x_1+....+x_n)^2}{(x_1^2+.....+x_n^2)}$

I am stuck with the form above. I see that this statement in true by plugging numbers in it, however I find it hard to proof it.

Instead of only give the solution, would it be possible to get feedback on the approach of finding such a proof?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1474752/11619) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498319/11619).

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1249986/11619) may be an even better duplicate target.